# Not able to read HDF5 file present in S3 in sagemaker notebook instance

Tags: amazon-s3, hdf5, amazon-sagemaker

My directory structure looks like this: `bucket-name/training/file.hdf5`

I tried reading this file in sagemaker notebook instance by this code cell:

```
bucket='bucket-name'
data_key = 'training/file.hdf5'
data_location = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, data_key)
hf = h5py.File(data_location, 'r')
```

But it gives me error:

```
Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 's3://bucket-name/training/file.hdf5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)
```

I have also tried `pd.read_hdf(data_location)` but was not succesfull.

Trying to read a csv file into dataframe from same key doesnt throw error.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking the question here!

Your file is on the remote storage service Amazon S3. The string `data_location` is not the name of a local file, hence your data reader cannot open it. It order to read the S3 file, you have 2 options:

- use a library that can read files from S3. It seems that [h5py can do that](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/file.html#file-drivers), if you specify `driver='ros3'`
- alternatively, you can also bring the file from S3 to your machine, and then read it from the machine. For example using the AWS CLI to bring the file from S3 to local `aws s3 cp s3://<your bucket>/<your file on s3> /home/ec2-user/SageMaker/` then `File(data_location='/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/your-file-name.hdf5')` should work